# Too many rows with Many To Many Relationship omines/datatables-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, datatables

I am using bundle omines/datatables-bundle to create tables in my Symfony application. When I create custom query that left joins with a field that has Many to Many relationship it returns too many rows.

I am using Symfony 4.2 and omines/datatables-bundle bundle. The end result it that I have wrong number of total results found and many blank pages in my table.

This is how my table is being created

```
class TestTableType implements DataTableTypeInterface
{
    public function configure(DataTable $dataTable, array $options)
    {
        $dataTable
            ->add('id',
                NumberColumn::class,
                array(
                    'label'            => 'ID',
                    'globalSearchable' => false
                )
            )
            ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class,
                array(
                    'entity' => Test::class,
                    'query'  => function (QueryBuilder $builder)
                    {
                        $builder
                            ->distinct()
                            ->select('t')
                            ->from(Test::class, 't')
                            ->leftJoin('t.products', 'prod');
                    }
                )
            )
        ;
    }
}
```

and this is how Many to Many relationship is defined in my entity class.

```
**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="tests")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_has_test")
*/
private $products;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

along with getters and setters

```
public function addProduct(\App\Entity\Product $product)
{
    $this->products[] = $product;

    return $this;
}

public function removeProduct(\App\Entity\Product $product)
{
    $this->products->removeElement($product);
}

public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->products;
}
```

What might be the cause of it? And how can I fix it?

Comment: try regular select without distinct to see which data is duplicated

Comment: change the leftJoin to `->innerJoin()`